# Which words are typical for the books or for the so-called "book vocabulary" specifically?

Tags: terminology, writing-style

My experience in English literature is quite limited yet, and thus I can't recall any words that we're most likely to encounter in a book rather than in a spoken or in a neutral language.

- The terms I've used here may not be the best because I don`t know their equivalents in English language.

Comment: I am not certain there is a definitive or likely list of words that are more likely written than spoken. The general direction would be the more obscure, the more polysyllabic, the less likely to be spoken, and more likely written, if and when used at all. Online dictionaries these days often have an indicator for “rarity”, and all dictionaries list number of syllables.

Comment: The following short article from _Lexico_ refers to the kind of vocabulary you are probably asking about as "_Literary language_": https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/literary-language

Comment: Yes, thank you, it`s what I was looking for